# How can I simplify this implicit equation to an explicit equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, calculus-and-analysis

How can I simplify this implicit equation to an explicit equation:

```
Tan[5 y/12] - (7 y/((x)^2 + (y)^2 - (3.5)^2)) == 0
```

i.e: $y=f(x)$ where $y$ is a explicit function of $x$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your **code** attempts, that means in Mathematica format and in a well [formatted way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). That helps people trying to help you so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), it will not give you $y(x)$ for that function, but you can get $x(y)$

```
Solve[-((7 y)/(-12.25 + x^2 + y^2)) + Tan[(5 y)/12] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -0.5 Sqrt[49. - 4. y^2 + 28. y Cot[0.416667 y]]}, {x -> 0.5 Sqrt[49. - 4. y^2 + 28. y Cot[0.416667 y]]}}
> ```

```
Plot[Evaluate[x /. %], {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And one could apply `InverseFunction` to the solutions.